# Meteor simple-schema: Setting a min/max constraint based on another field value

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

I'm using aldeed:simple-schema with Mongo collections in Meteor.

I have a collection that consists of a grid (x/y coordinates). It has fields describing the dimensions, and an array of points, which must not be out of bounds of those dimensions.

I'd like to be able to define a constraint on the coordinates that prevents them from being out of bounds for the grid. Here's what the thing I'm trying to do might look like:

```
MyGrid.attachSchema({
    gridWidth: {
        type: Number,
        min: 1,
        max: 100
    },
    gridHeight: {
        type: Number,
        min: 1,
        max: 100
    },
    gridPoints: {
        type: [Object],
        minCount: 0
    },

    // HERE is what I want to do
    'gridPoints.$.x': {
        type: Number,
        min: 0,
        max: gridWidth - 1 // <--- THIS
    },
    'gridPoints.$.x': {
        type: Number,
        min: 0,
        max: gridHeight - 1 // <--- THIS
    }
});
```

Is such a thing possible? I am not finding it in the simple-schema docs, so probably not, but it doesn't sound too far-fetched for these kinds of 'references' to be supported...

Answer (score 0):

There is custom validation in SimpleSchema.
Also, you might be "gilding the lily" here.

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#custom-validation